# Swap to front on linked list

Tags: java, linked-list

I am trying to add nodes to a linked list such that if a node containing the same information as the new node already exists, it moves to the front of the list and increments its counter. However, when I attempt this, I get a list shorter than expected. Also, the node count I keep says it is more than it should be. I have been over the code multiple times and cannot find the error. I am almost 100% certain that the error is in the add method. I have another list using a different add method (to swap one node higher up the list) but the same find method and it works fine. The list I am creating should have 561 nodes, however, it prints out 361 nodes and numElements returns 862.

```
public static void moveToFront(File FILE_NAME) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(FILE_NAME);                 //Scanner to read the words from the file

    if(FILE_NAME.exists())                                  //Make sure the file is legitimate
    {
        SwapToFirstList List3 = new SwapToFirstList();

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        while(input.hasNext())                          //While there are more words
        {
            //System.out.println(input.hasNext());
            String nextWord = input.next().replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z ]", "").toLowerCase();  //Remove all non-letters and convert
                                                                                        //letters to their lowercase form

                                                                                //If the word is already on the list        
            List3.add(nextWord);                                                //swap the node to the front of the list
                                                                                //If the word isn't on the list
                                                                                //add the word to the list
            //System.out.println(nextWord);
        }       

        long elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;

        input.close();                                                          //Close the scanner
        System.out.println("List Three Words: " + List3.totalCount());          //Print number of words on the list
        System.out.println("List Three Nodes: " + List3.size());                //Print number of nodes on the list
        System.out.println("List Three Compares: " + List3.comparisons());      //Print out the number of comparisons for the list
        System.out.println("List Three Ref Changes: " + List3.refChanges());    //Print out the number of reference changes
        System.out.println(List3.toString());                                   //Print out the unsorted list
        System.out.println("List Three Time: " + elapsedTime / 1000.0 + " seconds.");
    }

    else                                            //File does not exist
        System.out.println("File Not Found");
}

public void add(T element)
//moves the node to the front of the list
{
    find(element);
    if(!found)
    //element is not on the list
    {
        Node<T> newNode = new Node<T>(element);
        totalCount++;
        newNode.addCount();
        newNode.setLink(list);
        list = newNode;
        refChanges++;
        numElements++;
    }
    else
    //element is already on the list
    {
        if(location == list)
        //element is at the front of the list
        {
            getNode(element).addCount();
            totalCount++;
        }
        else
        //element is not at the front of the list
        {
            previous.setLink(location.getLink());
            location.setLink(list.getLink());
            location.addCount();
            totalCount++;
            list = location;
        }
    }
}

protected void find(T target)
//searches the list for the target
{
    location = list;
    previous = null;
    refChanges++;
    found = false;

    while(location != null)
    //while the list is not empty
    {
        numComparisons++;
        if(location.getInfo().equals(target))
        //if the item matches what we are searching for
        {
            found = true;
            return;
        }
        else
        //go to the next node
        {
            preprevious = previous;
            previous = location;
            location = location.getLink();
            refChanges += 3;
        }
    }
}

public void setLink(Node<T> link)
//set the link for this node
{
    this.link = link;
}

public Node<T> getLink()
//return the link of this node
{
    return link;
}
```

Comment: If the element is already in the list, you are not adding it; you are increasing its "count", so you don't need to increment `totalCount`. As to your other issue, you have not provided enough information to determine the cause. I imagine it has to do with the `setLink()` method.

Comment: I added some more of the methods it uses. Let me know if there are any others you need to see.

Comment: A sidenote: you should first make sure that the file exists and then open the Scanner, otherwise the `new Scanner(FILE_NAME)` will throw a `FileNotFoundException` if the file does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

I think, the `location.setLink(list.getLink())` line is the problem.

If `list` is the first element in the list, `list.getLink()` is the second. So you are setting the next element after `location` to the second element in the list. This in turn means that you are ***replacing*** the first node in the list with `location`, instead of ***prepending*** `location` to the list.

To solve this, replace the above line with:

```
location.setLink(list);
```